# How to remove vertical spacing between form fields?

Tags: html, css, forms

So I noticed that when you change the font-family in CSS it changes the vertical spacing between form fields. I was wondering if there was a way in CSS to remove some of that spacing to make a form more compact. Using the following increases spacing:

```
input { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

I would like to decrease spacing, i.e., equivalent to the following:

```
input { margin-bottom: -10px; }
```

except that doesn't do anything below 0px. I'm a bit new to CSS and web development in general so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] reproducing your problem.

Comment: Please add a code to reproduce your problem

Comment: You say it's related to your font family. Checking `line-height` might be a place to look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to replicate your issue in Firefox (chrome didn't showcase the same issue).  It appeared to happen only on some types of fonts and only when the input container was set to display block. One way to fix the issue, was to set the input container to display:flex and the flex-direction to column. See my snippet below showcasing the above.

```css
.testsection2{
    display: block;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
.testsection3{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
     background-color: aqua;
}

.testsection2>input{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif
}
.testsection3>input{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif
}
section{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: solid 2px black;
  
}
```

```html
<section class="testsection2">
        <h3>Container: Display Block</h3>
       <p>Notice the margin variance (although slight) between inputs when they start stacking. Confirmed in firefox, not chrome though. </p>
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
    </section>

    <section class="testsection3">
        <h3>Container: Display Flex, Direction Column</h3>
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
        <input type="text" class="testinput" value="Some Text">
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the input to display: block;
Even better would be a div around the input.